# How to calculate enthalpy change of neutralisation - what mass?

Tags: physical-chemistry, heat, enthalpy

How to calculate enthalpy change of neutralisation - what mass?

I made an experiment where I reacted 100ml HCL 2M with 100ml NaOH 2M in 1300ml Water, and got a temperature change dT.

My question is do i use 1500g in the formula, Q=mcdT ?

c (specific heat capacity) will be calculated from another experiment where I measure the work required to heat the same solution to ~dT. In wheere I also need this mass

Do I include the small amount of HCl and NaOH?

Many thanks!

Comment: You should use the same total mass as in the neutralization experiment.  And, in your work experiment, the total mass of solution and the concentration of salt should be the same as for the final state of your neutralization.